# Applying function to unique values for efficiency in pandas

Tags: pandas

This is a general question about how to apply a function efficiently in pandas. I often encounter situations where I need to apply a function to a `pd.Series` and it would be faster to apply the function only to unique values.

For example, suppose I have a very large dataset. One column is `date`, and I want to add a column that gives the last date of the quarter for `date`. I would do this:

```
mf['qtr'] = pd.Index(mf['date']) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
```

But for large data sets, this can take a while. So to speed it up, I'll extract the unique values of `date`, apply the function to those, and then merge it back in to the original data:

```
dts = mf['date'].drop_duplicates()
eom = Series(pd.Index(dts) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0), index=dts)
eom.name = 'qtr'
mf = pd.merge(mf, eom.reset_index())
```

This can be much faster than the one-liner above.

So here's my question: Is this really the right way to do things like this, or is there a better approach?

And, would it make sense and be feasible to add a feature to pandas that would take this unique/apply/merge approach automatically? (It wouldn't work for certain functions, such as those that rely on rolling data, so presumably the user would have to explicitly request this behavior.)

Comment: I admittedly don't work with dates that much, but this result is pretty surprising to me since merges aren't generally very fast.  I'd have to think this is fairly uncommon and only happens if you have a really slow function  that hasn't yet been cythonized.  I think it's also likely to depend on the number of unique/duplicate values so it would be good if you could provide some code to generate a sample dataset.

Comment: FWIW, here's some sample data for which the merge way is about twice as fast for me:  `mf = pd.DataFrame({'date':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365,  freq='D'), 900)})`

Comment: Why don't you group on the date and call your function on the groups?

Comment: @EdChum, that's great, didn't think of that! I'm having trouble writing a function that works on grouped data. Can you post it as an answer and I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally just group on the date column and then just call your function for each group:

```
mf.groupby('date',as_index=False)['date'].apply(lambda x: x + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0))
```

I think should work

**EDIT**

OK the above doesn't work but the following does but I think this is a bit twisted:

```
mf.groupby('date', as_index=False)['date'].apply(lambda x: (pd.Index(x)+ QuarterEnd(0))[0])
```

we create a datetimeindex for each date, add the offset and then access the single element to return the value but personally I think this is not great.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives `TypeError: cannot use a non-absolute DateOffset in datetime/timedelta operations [<0 * QuarterEnds: startingMonth=3>]`. Is it because `date` isn't an index?

Comment: not sure could you try `mf.groupby('date',as_index=False)['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Index(x) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0))` this isn't ideal though

Comment: Actually can you try `from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
mf.groupby('date',as_index=False)['date'].apply(lambda x: x + QuarterEnd(0))`

Comment: Your first suggestion returns a series of DatetimeIndex and doesn't look quite right; not sure what it's doing. The second suggestion gives the same error as originally. The test data in @JohnE's comment above gives same results.

Comment: OK I see the issue this seems to do what you want but I don't think this is ideal `mf.groupby('date', as_index=False)['date'].apply(lambda x: (pd.Index(x)+ QuarterEnd(0))[0])` So because we create a datetimeindex object for each value I just access the first element so it returns a datetime

Comment: I think the problem here is the restriction that the offset objects only work on datetimeindex objects so really perhaps your method is the best at the moment

Comment: OK, this works, and thanks. As I mentioned, this is a specific example of a more general issue that comes up. I think your solution of using `groupby` will generally work.

Comment: @itzy Doesn't the `apply` need to be `transform` if you are going to be back to your full size data and not a collapsed version?  I.e. don't you still need to merge here?  Also, when I time this, it's actually slower than either of the original methods and I thought the point of this whole thing was speed?  (Perhaps my timing was off though, you can check yourself, of course)  But to be clear, I do think the `groupby` with `transform` is probably the most clear and readable approach.  It's just not any sort of speed improvement that I can see.

Comment: @JohnE I agree that this method of temporary index construction doesn't feel right to me, the OP's original method seems fine to me, not sure if `mf['date'].unique()` or `mf['date'].drop_duplicates()` is quicker here